# Is the series $\sum(-1)^n(2^{\frac{1}{n}} - 1)$ convergent? absolutely?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Is the series $\sum(-1)^n(2^{\frac{1}{n}} - 1)$ convergent? Does it converge absolutely?

Comment: What do you think yourself? What do you know about convergent / absolutely convergent series that seem like it could be relevant here?

Comment: Think about the alternating series test

Comment: You can try the generalized binomial theorem on $(1+1)^{1/n}-1$.

Comment: Find an equivalent of $2^{1/n}-1$ writing $2^{1/n}=\exp(\ln(2)/n)$ and developing $\exp$ in $0$

Comment: Thanks for the hints so far, I was able to prove convergence using the alternating series test! Now on to the absolutely convergence :)

Comment: i dont think it converges absolutely, try the comparison test

Comment: $\ln(2)>\frac 12$ then show $f(t)=2^t-1-\frac t2$ is positive for $t>0$. (show $f\ \nearrow$). Use to prove $|a_n|>\frac 1{2n}$ which is term of a divergent series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The series converges. To show this we can use the alternating series test. It is easy to check that the sequence $b_n=2^{\frac{1}{n}} - 1$ is monotone decreasing. Therefore it suffices to show $\lim_{x\to\infty} (2^{\frac{1}{n}} - 1)= 0$. Notice:
$$(\lim_{x\to\infty} 2^{\frac{1}{n}} - 1)=\lim_{x\to\infty} 2^{\frac{1}{n}} - \lim_{x\to\infty} 1 =\lim_{x\to\infty} 2^{\frac{1}{n}} - 1$$

since $f(x) = 2^\frac{1}{x}$ is continuous $$\lim_{x\to\infty} 2^{\frac{1}{n}}= 2^{\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}} = 2^0=1$$

Therefore $$b_n \to 0$$

Hence the series converges by the alternating series test.

Answer (score 0):

As @SamaelManasseh showed it's **conditionally** convergent.

But he was wrong in **absolutely** convergent proof! Notice he must write, $\sum(\frac{1}{n}-1)$, that he missed the parentheses. And in this case, $(\frac{1}{n}-1 < 0)$, that fails in comparison test.

But you can follow what @zwim said in comment:
$$f(t) = 2^t - 1 - \frac{t}{2}$$
$$f'(t) = 2^t\ln(2) - \frac{1}{2}$$
$$t>0 \Longrightarrow 2^t>1 \overset{\ln(2)>\frac{1}{2}}{==\Longrightarrow} 2^t\ln(2)>\frac{1}{2} \Longrightarrow f'(t)>0 \overset{f(0)=0}{==\Longrightarrow}$$
$$\overset{f(0)=0}{==\Longrightarrow} f(t)>0 \Longrightarrow 2^t - 1>\frac{t}{2} \Longrightarrow 2^{\frac{1}{n}} - 1>\frac{1}{2n}$$
That's a **positive** divergent series which shows your series isn't absolutely divergent by comparison test.

Comment: ahhh thank you, I missed that.